# Is it valid to dispatch multiple times inside redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to wrap my head around Redux or state management in general for the front-end applications.

As far as I know, there are three basic libraries to create complex actions logic: `redux-thunk`, `redux-saga` and `redux-observable`.

I'm using `redux-thunk` to create a chain of the async operations, but I found them a little bit inappropriate: action creators should create actions, not functions.

In order to get around this, I've created actions (simple action creators) and operations (thunks) with `redux-toolkit`, but I still see them a little bit confusing:

- **reducers.js** (they also represent actions):

```
export function add(state, action) { ... }
export function added(state, action) { ... }
```

- **operations.js** (they are performing complex actions logic):

```
export function addItem(payload) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actions.add(payload))

    const { data } = await Items.create(action.payload); 

    dispatch(actions.added(payload))
  }
}
```

It looks ok, but I can see myself trying to dispatch `add` directly  in the future.

---

Using `redux-saga` seems unnatural thanks to the generator syntax. I don't have to say anything about `redux-observable`, it's over-complicated for this simple task.

So I tried to use simple custom middleware for this kind of work, but I don't really know if it's a "good practice" or "bad practice". However, it allows to use simple actions to fire an observer that dispatches matching function:

- **middlewares/observer.js (simplified):**

```
let listeners = {}

export const observer = store => next => action => {
  const result = next(action)

  if (action.type in listeners) {
    listeners[action.type](store.dispatch, action)
  }

  return result
}

export const createListener = (action, listener) => {
  listeners[action.type] = listener
}
```

Code above allows to write "observers" / "listeners" like below:

```
createListener(actions.add, async (dispatch, action) => {
  const { data } = await Items.create(action.payload)

  dispatch(actions.added(data))
})
```

...which allows to dispatch callback attached to the listened actions. Looks very simple and clean for me.

Is this a bad way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer and creator of Redux Toolkit.

[Thunks exist to allow you to move complex synchronous and semi-complex async logic outside of components](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial#thinking-in-thunks).  Components typically use action creators to avoid knowing the details of how to define a given action object.  Thunk action creators exist to provide parallel syntax, allowing components to kick off logic without needing to know the details of whether it's a simple action dispatch or something more complex.

That said, thunks do *not* give you a way to respond to dispatched actions, because the only thing the thunk middleware does is look to see if you've passed a thunk function to `dispatch`, and if so, call it.  Sagas and observables both provide APIs that let you run additional logic in response to dispatched actions.  See [the Redux FAQ entry on "how do I choose between thunks, sagas, and observables?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#what-async-middleware-should-i-use-how-do-you-decide-between-thunks-sagas-observables-or-something-else) for more details.

The middleware you've just shown there is a typical example of a simple "action listener" middleware - really a much simpler version of what sagas and observables let you do.  In fact, [we're hoping to add a similar middleware to Redux Toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/237), but haven't done so yet.

So, yes, the middleware itself is a valid tool to create, but you haven't provided sufficient information on what specific problem you're trying to solve, so I can't say whether it's an appropriate tool for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
Well, basically I'm trying to use the simplest solution (without much boilerplate) to execute asynchronous state changes by dispatching actions only. Doing that without separation by "action creators" and "operations", where some changes could be dispatched by calling actions and some by operations. And I don't want to copy,wrap & re-rexport simple "actions" (that could change something) in "operations" file. I don't want to create a mess in the code.

Comment: To clarify, I just want to have separation of the concerns: actions should be interpreted as-is in the reducers, and they should be the only way to change state.  `createSlice` inside `redux-toolkit` automatically creates simple actions (which is nice - allows to remove boilerplate), but they aren't thunks. I don't want to think about "raw actions" and "complex actions (thunks)", just "actions".

Comment: They _are_ different things, but triggered in the same way: dispatching.  You can only cause a state update by dispatching a plain action object.  Thunks may dispatch actions and run additional logic, but need access to the store to make that happen.  See [What is a "thunk"](https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/)? and ["Thinking in Thunks"](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial#thinking-in-thunks) for explanations on how this fits into the Redux dataflow.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept of the "thunk", and problem that I've encountered will be somewhat fixed with the middleware that you're working on, or my custom one. Thank you.